# Program doesn't copy files properly

Tags: c++

**It just copies the first letter of the file name and file type is .file instead of the real one.**

*The program can be used to sort and copy files into different directories (years and quarters) according to their LastWriteTime.*

```
void sort(std::string quartal, const char * c_pfad, SYSTEMTIME datum, WIN32_FIND_DATA *wfd_p){
            year = datum.wYear;
            str_year =  patch::to_string(year);             // convert

            year_path = dir + str_year + "\\";  // C:\\Pictures\\2015\\

            CreateDirectory(convert(year_path), NULL);                              // year-dir

            quartal_path = year_path + quartal; // C:\\Pictures\\2015\\Erstes Quartal\\

            CreateDirectory(convert(quartal_path), NULL);                               // quarter-dir

            ziel = quartal_path + *wfd_p->cFileName;

            CopyFile( c_pfad, convert(ziel), false ); 

}

void schleife(const char* file){
WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;
HANDLE fHandle = FindFirstFile(file,&wfd);


do 
{ 
    // Neither . nor ..  (subdirectories) 
    if (!( (wfd.cFileName[0]=='.') && ( (wfd.cFileName[1]=='.' && wfd.cFileName[2]==0) || wfd.cFileName[1]==0 ) )) 
    { 
        if (wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) 
        { 

              findDirGes = findDirGes.substr (0, findDirGes.size()-1) + wfd.cFileName + "\\*";
              schleife(convert(findDirGes));                             // no file but directory

        } 
        else 
        { 
           pfad = findDirGes.substr (0, findDirGes.size()-1) + wfd.cFileName;



          WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA dateidaten; 

          GetFileAttributesEx(convert(pfad), GetFileExInfoStandard, &dateidaten); 
          // cprintf("\n %d", dateidaten.ftLastWriteTime); 

          FILETIME test = dateidaten.ftLastWriteTime; 
          // cprintf("\n %d", test); 
          SYSTEMTIME datum; 

          FileTimeToSystemTime(&test, &datum);


        switch (datum.wMonth){
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            sort("Erstes Quartal\\", convert(pfad), datum, &wfd );
            break;
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
            sort("Zweites Quartal\\", convert(pfad), datum, &wfd );
            break;
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9:
            sort("Drittes Quartal\\", convert(pfad), datum, &wfd );
            break;
        case 10:
        case 11:
        case 12:
            sort("Viertes Quartal\\", convert(pfad), datum, &wfd );
            break;
  }

        } 
    } 
} 
while (FindNextFile(fHandle,&wfd)); 
FindClose(fHandle);
}
```

*The problem of the program is that it goes through all the files in the directory you typed in and if it comes to another directory it sorts and copies the files perfectly but after that it doesn't continue with the files (or directories) in the directory above.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.`

Comment: What do you want me to add?

Comment: Exactly what is in @Jashaszun's comment.  The shortest code necessary to reproduce it.

Comment: I want you to add `a specific problem or error` (specifically, *what* and *where* -- I realize you already have the *what*), and I want the `shortest code necessary`.

Comment: @Jashaszun Please don't mark your entire comment as code.

Comment: What we ask you to do is described here: [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) usually, when you do this, you may even be able to figure out the bug yourself.

Comment: I marked the probable position of the problem and shortened the code

Comment: Added some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Using only one global variable `WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;` for all the recursive calls is an error. Use a separate **local** variable each time you need to recurse.

```
void schleife(const char* file)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd; // local variable
    HANDLE fHandle = FindFirstFile(file, &wfd);
    do
    {
        ...
        schleife(convert(findDirGes)); // recursive call
        ...
    }
    while (FindNextFile(fHandle, &wfd)); 
    FindClose(fHandle);
}
```

Comment: Could you pls show me how to do that? And remind that when I delete the lines fHandle = fHandleBef it doesn't return an error but doesn't work as wanted (see description).

Comment: @Yannik The error you describe 'it doesn't continue with the files (or directories) in the directory above' is exactly the problem caused by using one global variable. When you start a second find in a subdirectory it messes with the find in the first directory because you reuse the same variable. This is one (of many) reasons not to use global variables.

Comment: But another problem is that I use this variable in the main and sort function, so i can't make it a local variable.

Comment: @Yannik You don't have to use it in the main function. It's only because you wrongly call FindFileFirst in the main function that you think you have to use it there. The correct place for FindFileFirst is in the schleife function. You can pass a pointer parameter to this variable to the sort function so you can use it there as well. You should get out of the bad habit of using global variables.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far but after I changed the things you named it still has the problem I described in the updated question and another problem (title and first lines) appeared.

Comment: One of your problems is easy to solve `ziel = quartal_path + *wfd_p->cFileName;` should be `ziel = quartal_path + wfd_p->cFileName;`. You get the first character only because of the `*` in `*wfd_p->cFileName`.